# Username text design distortion for all pages of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, bug, design, firefox, display-names

Just observed today, while I was browsing my answers on Stack Overflow:

[image]

As you can see, the letter V's starting point is hidden due to the shadow on the profile image.

This is the area where it is visible:

[image]

There is more of it:-
See the following screenshot:- 
[image]

Here also we can see, the name jonrsharpe that has edited my question, the letter "j" is not complete , it seems like "i". Seems a major issue for reading the username.

Comment: How/why do you get a shadow on your profile image?

Comment: @BillWoodger: That's an "Expanded usercard", which is a perk of being an ["Established user"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) (Halfway down that page)

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks. There's some irony in this tiny issue then :-)

Comment: Quick workaround, then: don't start your username with a capital V. Unless you are on Meta, where it is OK...

Comment: Seems to work fine on my machine in Chrome and Firefox. IE however does appear to have a bit of a pixel snip. but it doesn't look anywhere near as dramatic as the image shown.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8, this appears to be relevant: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/ie11-on-windows-81-font-rendering-still-atrocious/f36cf5e2-c88c-47c2-9491-7b13d57f39f7?auth=1

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus. for the short description. It seems a genuine issue .. I guess.

Comment: @BillWoodger- This is also happening for lowercase letter too. See my updated question.